# magento import product form csv file with image url and category name

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have problem importing product to magento using `CSV` file

I have image `url` instead of image `path` , how can I save image from url as default magento takes path

2. it is difficult for layman to get `category` id and put in `csv` file.

I want to import product via catrgory name

```
cat 1 > child cat 1 > sub cat > rest product detail
```

how can I do this is there any module to do this

Comment: try magmi http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                    ->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
                    ->setAttributeSetId(8)
                    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
                    ->setSku('adb') //SKU
                    ->setName('Title')
                    ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                    ->setPrice(3.1)
                    ->setDescription('This is Des');
```

Above code is use to get collection and set data.

Now to set category from category name you can try below code:

```
$category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'category_name');
                    $cat_det=$category->getData();
                    $main_cat = $cat_det[0]['entity_id'];

$sub_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'sub_cat_name');
                    $sub_cat_det=$sub_category->getData();
                    $main_sub_cat = $sub_cat_det[0]['entity_id'];

                    $product->setCategoryIds(array($main_cat, $main_sub_cat));
$product->save();
}
catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

If you still have any query feel free to ask.

Comment: Create a sandbox file and run this script.